# Toggle background color with click in and out

Tags: toggle

I have a script that works great, but I need the background color to return to its original state when you leave or click outside the .test

Is there a way to make it toggle back after clicking out of the .test?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            var input = document.getElementById("test");

         input.onclick = function ()
         {
         document.getElementById("quote_input").style.backgroundColor = "#AAB3AA";
         document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "#AAB3AA";

 };});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the old background color in another variable, or as an attribute on the element, and then on the `onmouseout` event, you would read that attribute and reverse the backgrounds.

Comment: @Erik - You can store the current background color to an attribute on the element itself. And then use read that when the next event comes